# Data storage IEEE754 with little and big endian

Tags: floating-point, endianness

I’m learning some IT stuff currently and have got a probably pretty simple question..
I got the task to calculate the decimal output of a memory dump of 4 bytes, stored as little endian (IEEE754). My books only explained how to deal with the kind of calculation when the data is stored like:

```
|--------- Byte 1 --------|--------- Byte 2 -------------|--------- Byte 3 ------------|--------- Byte 4 ------|
|sign e7 e6 e5 e4 e3 e2 e1|e0 m22 m21 m20 m19 m18 m17 m16|m15 m14 m13 m12 m11 m10 m9 m8|m7 m6 m5 m4 m3 m2 m1 m0|
```

I don’t have any helpful description of little/big endian…
I spent a lot of time and figured out that the table above must be stored as big endian. The description for little endian says that the first byte will be on position of the 4th byte, the second on position 3, the third on position two and the fourth on the first adress.

```
Example:
Big endian: AB CD EF 01
Little endian: 01 EF CD AB
```

Am i right with this?

I’m slightly confused now, because this must mean that e.g. the bit for the sign of the number is the first one of the AB Byte, isn’t it?
Can someone confirm or explain if the following table is properly „transfered“ to little endian:

```
|--------- Byte 1 ------|--------- Byte 2 ------------|--------- Byte 3 -------------|--------- Byte 4 --------|
|m7 m6 m5 m4 m3 m2 m1 m0|m15 m14 m13 m12 m11 m10 m9 m8|e0 m22 m21 m20 m19 m18 m17 m16|sign e7 e6 e5 e4 e3 e2 e1|
```

Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is perfectly correct. It can be easily verified with a simple program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  float f=-123456.75f;
  int i;
  unsigned char c[4];

  memcpy(c,&f,4);
  memcpy(&i,&f,4);
  printf("decimal representation of f: %f\n",f);
  printf("hex representation of f: %a\n",f);
  printf("hex value of integer with the same bytes as f:  %x\n",i);
  printf("sucessive bytes in f (0:3): %.2x %.2x %.2x %.2x\n",c[0],c[1],c[2],c[3]);
  /* gives
decimal representation of f: -123456.750000
hex representation of f: -0x1.e240cp+16
hex value of integer with the same bytes as f:  c7f12060
sucessive bytes in f (0:3): 60 20 f1 c7
  */
}
```

> I’m slightly confused now, because this must mean that e.g. the bit for the sign of the number is the first one of the AB Byte, isn’t it?

No reason to be confused. In memory, sign bit will indeed be the MSB of the fourth byte of a float representation on a little endian architecture.
But endianness only concerns how bytes are **stored** in memory. Whatever the endianness, once loaded in a register and manipulated by a program, the behavior will be identical.
We are used to write left to right and to start numbers by the most significant digit. But other representation schemes are perfectly valid provided the mathematical properties are kept.
If it can help you, write the bytes with the least significant bit at the left (but right and left have no meaning on a computer).

```
|--------- Byte 1 ------|--------- Byte 2 ------------|--------- Byte 3 -------------|--------- Byte 4 --------|
|m0 m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 m7|m8 m0 m10 m11 m12 m13 m14 m15|m16 m17 m18 m19 m20 m21 m22 e0|e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 sign|
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
One last question: The following data is stored in these four bytes:

    Byte 1, adress 0x100: AA (hex);
    Byte 2, adress 0x101: BB;
    Byte 3, adress 0x102: CC;
    Byte 4, adress 0x103: DD;

This means the sign is the position highlighted in this dual number: **1**1011101, right? Is the order of how the bytes are stored like i just described or is it vice versa?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be, but it depends on your hardware. Use the provided code and change the sign of the number. The position of sign bit will be obvious by considering results for the positive and negative numbers.